# Tkinter でボタンが押されたときに別のオブジェクトの表示を変更したい

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinterでGUI画面を作成しており、Frameによりオブジェクトを分けて実装しています。
その一部の内部ボタンを押すと、別のFrameの表示を変更しようとしています。

下記のコードのように、呼び出し元自体をFrameオブジェクトに渡してしまえば、呼び出し元のメソッドを通じて別のFrameに変更を加えられます。

もっとスマートな書き方はないでしょうか？

```
from tkinter import *

class class_Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = 0
        self.root = Tk()

        self.iTopFrame = class_TopFrame(self,self.root)
        self.iMainFrame = class_MainFrame(self,self.root)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def TopClicked(self):
        self.mode  = 1-self.mode
        self.iMainFrame.set_widget(self.mode)

        pass

class class_TopFrame():
    def __init__(self,parent,root):

        _InFrame_ = Frame(root)
        self.Button = Button(_InFrame_,text='change',command=parent.TopClicked)

        self.Button.grid()
        _InFrame_.grid()

class class_MainFrame():
    def __init__(self,parent,root):

        _InFrame_ = Frame(root)
        self.mode = 0

        self.Button1 = Button(_InFrame_,text='mode1')
        self.Button2 = Button(_InFrame_,text='mode2')
        self.Button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Button2.grid(row=0,column=0)

        _InFrame_.grid()

        self.set_widget(self.mode)

    def set_widget(self,mode):
        if mode == 0:
            self.Button2.grid_remove()
            self.Button1.grid()
        else:
            self.Button1.grid_remove()
            self.Button2.grid()

class_Main().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

呼び出し元でボタンとイベントを[バインド](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events)する方法があります。
スマートかどうかは分かりませんが、バインドを使うことで呼び出し元がMVVMのViewModelっぽくオブジェクト間の通信を制御することができます。
各Frame(MVVMのView)はそれぞれのFrame内部の制御のみに集中できるので、今回の例で言えば呼び出し元に`TopClicked`イベントがあるかどうかを`class_TopFrame`側が気にしなくて良くなります。

```
from tkinter import *

class class_Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = 0
        self.root = Tk()

        self.iTopFrame = class_TopFrame(self.root)
        self.iMainFrame = class_MainFrame(self.root)
        # 主な修正箇所
        self.iTopFrame.Button.bind("<Button-1>", self.TopClicked)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def TopClicked(self, event):
        self.mode  = 1-self.mode
        self.iMainFrame.set_widget(self.mode)

        pass

class class_TopFrame():
    def __init__(self,root):

        _InFrame_ = Frame(root)
        self.Button = Button(_InFrame_,text='change')

        self.Button.grid()
        _InFrame_.grid()

class class_MainFrame():
    def __init__(self,root):

        _InFrame_ = Frame(root)
        self.mode = 0

        self.Button1 = Button(_InFrame_,text='mode1')
        self.Button2 = Button(_InFrame_,text='mode2')
        self.Button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Button2.grid(row=0,column=0)

        _InFrame_.grid()

        self.set_widget(self.mode)

    def set_widget(self,mode):
        if mode == 0:
            self.Button2.grid_remove()
            self.Button1.grid()
        else:
            self.Button1.grid_remove()
            self.Button2.grid()

class_Main().run()
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。なるほどこういう方法もありますね。しかしながら、この質問に表現できない部分で、Frame間のドラッグアンドドロップを実装するのにrootにマウスイベントをいくつかBindしているため、これは使用できない方法なのです。これはこれでよいと思います。